# How to change Speed of Add Movement Input in Unreal Engine 5 BP

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

This is a Pawn class

This is the default I tried:
[image]

I tried:
[image]

But this makes no difference.
How to change the speed?

Answer (score 1):

The movement input, as suggested by the pin's name, is the direction vector where you *intend* for your Character to move. To manipulate the movement speed (and other character movement properties) you can tune the tunables found on the `Character Movement` component on a `Character` class:

[image]

You can also change some (not all) of the parameters available at runtime using functions and setters similar to any other component manipulation in Unreal.